# I need put log scale in colormap in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I used gnuplot, but decided to use tikz now.
When I need put log scale in colorbar in gnuplot 
I write `logscale cb`.
What options for tikz?

Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{minimal}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\input{u10cxz.tikz}
\end{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={\footnotesize $x$ [$m$]},ylabel={\footnotesize $z$[$m$]},zlabel={\footnotesize $C$ [$g/m^3$]},
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        view={120}{40},
        grid=both,
        colormap,
        colorbar]
        \addplot3 [surf,x domain=0:12,y domain=30:70, z domain=0:0.00006, samples=50] table[x index=0,y index=2,z index=4]{data/u10cxz.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It would be helpful if you could show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: The `tikz-pgf`, `tikz-3dplot` and `tikzscale` tags are poorly chosen: you may use only `pgfplots` tag. Otherwise, you may give a *complete* example with a `\documentclass` and all `\usepackage` (as `\usepackage{pgfplots}`).

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples. It is not suitable. Why are you loading lots of packages you don't use - at least for the example? And why do you have stuff after `\end{document}`? What is in `u10cxz.tikz`? Why do you load `graphics` as well as `graphicx`?